# How to install Dataflow library in .Net v 4 project?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, dataflow

I need to **install system.threading.task.dataflow** library in a project targeting **.netv 4 client** **profile**. How can I install it in my project as I cannot update my project framework?

Thanks in advance if anyone helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in case any other needs it I mention here:

```
Install-Package HomeLab.Tpl.DataFlow -Version 4.0.0
```

Install it through package manager console window.